# How to convert html file to pdf using javascript which include css in style tag

Tags: javascript

How i can convert html file to pdf anybody please help me and that page which contain a button on clicking the button the pdf will be saved to the client comouter and in pdf there is no image of the button

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="js/invoice.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Invoice Premimum Buses</title>
<style>

@font-face {
font-family: SourceSansPro;
src:  url('fonts/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg');
 }

.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 }

 a {
color: #0087C3;
text-decoration: none;
 }

 body {
position: relative;
width: 21cm;  
height: 29.7cm; 
margin: 0 auto; 
color: #555555;
background: #FFFFFF; 
font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 14px; 
font-family: SourceSansPro;
}

header {
padding: 10px 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

#logo {
float: left;
margin-top: 8px;
}

#logo img {
height: 70px;
}

#company {
float: right;
text-align: right;
}


#details {
margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

#client {
 padding-left: 6px;
 border-left: 6px solid #0087C3;
 float: left;
}

#client .to {
color: #777777;
}

h2.name {
font-size: 1.4em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
}

#invoice {
float: right;
text-align: right;
}

#invoice h1 {
color: #0087C3;
font-size: 2.4em;
line-height: 1em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0  0 10px 0;
  }



table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 }

 table th {
white-space: nowrap;        
font-weight: normal;
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-ticket">
    <header class="clearfix">
     <div id="company">
    <h2 class="name">Premimum Buses</h2>
    <div>Dr AIT Banglore</div>
    <div>(+91) 87099-60796</div>
    <div>divprnc@gmail.com</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </header>
<main>
<div id="details" class="clearfix">
   <div id="client">
    <div class="to">INVOICE TO:</div>
    <h2 class="name" id="cname">John Doe</h2>
    <div class="email" id="cemail">kmrprnc@gmail.com</div>
    <div class="email" id="cfrom">From</div>
    <div class="email" id="ctoo">To</div>
  </div>
  <div id="invoice">
    <h1 id="tour-name">Tour Name</h1>
    <div class="date" id="order-id">order-id : sdfjasddfkjasdldfjk</div>
    <div class="date" id="boarding-time">Boarding Time: 9:00</div>
    <div class="date" id="departure-date">Departure Date: 30/06/2014</div>
  </div>
</div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="no">#</th>
      <th class="desc">Name</th>
      <th class="unit">Age</th>
      <th class="qty">Gender</th>
      <th class="qty">Seat Number</th>
      <th class="total">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="set-data-cust">
    <!-- <tr>
        <td class="no">01</td>
        <td class="desc"><h3>Website Design</h3></td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">30</td>
        <td class="qty">30</td>
        <td class="total">$1,200.00</td>
      </tr> -->
    <!-- <tr>
        <td class="no">02</td>
        <td class="desc"><h3>Website Development</h3></td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">80</td>
        <td class="qty">80</td>
        <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="no">03</td>
        <td class="desc"><h3>Search Engines Optimization</h3></td>
        <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
        <td class="qty">20</td>
        <td class="qty">20</td>
        <td class="total">$800.00</td>
      </tr> -->
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td id="sub-price">s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">GST 10%</td>
      <td id="tax"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
      <td id="grand-total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<div id="thanks">Thank you!</div>
<div id="notices">
  <div>NOTICE:</div>
  <div class="notice">Please pay the price at the bus stop</div>
</div>
</main>


 </div>
 <div>

  <button id="down" onclick="download()"> Download Your Ticket</button>
 </div>
</body>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>


<script>
 function download() {

var doc = new jsPDF();
var ticket = document.getElementById("main-ticket")
doc.fromHTML(ticket, 15,15);
doc.save("ticket.pdf");
}
</script>
```

I have done this code and it is saving only a blank sheet and the html consist of style tag which i have added some styles

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have edited what i have done

Comment: doc is not defined means jsPDF is not initialized at this moment. Make sure you call your main js after jquery and jspdf file.

Comment: Also can you share your html file as well?

Comment: Actually i have changed the code it is saving the pdf but it is empty means a blank page

Comment: Go step by step. Put the debugger under  the line of var doc = new jsPDF(); And then check.

Comment: I have uploaded the html which i have changed the code can you please verify

Comment: It consist a div element of id "main-ticket" and i want to convert it into html and it also contains a button which i do not want to include

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213464/discussion-between-devang-and-divyanshu-bhaskar).

Comment: Put "<div id="main-ticket">" than class. It should work,

Comment: I am still facing issue
actully <script src="js/invoice.js"></script> from this script i am setting the data to the tables

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: In js pdf we have to write the each and every line what we can write to the pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have updated the code. It should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="main-ticket">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus minima minus sint, perspiciatis maiores fugit sit aperiam modi, nihil molestiae natus repellendus odit harum amet veniam. Officia incidunt perferendis vero impedit ullam deleniti facilis dolorum! Incidunt excepturi harum minima eos accusamus, iure aut mollitia commodi, hic culpa blanditiis optio fugiat quia voluptates suscipit placeat recusandae? Perferendis nobis autem ex dolor velit, quo explicabo, reiciendis facere tempora aperiam temporibus laborum dolorum dignissimos in delectus culpa aliquid error vitae suscipit. Accusamus, assumenda dolore voluptatibus officia provident qui dolorem ab fuga. Obcaecati, molestias placeat neque cum perspiciatis repellendus sequi earum. Velit, totam quae.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus minima minus sint, perspiciatis maiores fugit sit aperiam modi, nihil molestiae natus repellendus odit harum amet veniam. Officia incidunt perferendis vero impedit ullam deleniti facilis dolorum! Incidunt excepturi harum minima eos accusamus, iure aut mollitia commodi, hic culpa blanditiis optio fugiat quia voluptates suscipit placeat recusandae? Perferendis nobis autem ex dolor velit, quo explicabo, reiciendis facere tempora aperiam temporibus laborum dolorum dignissimos in delectus culpa aliquid error vitae suscipit. Accusamus, assumenda dolore voluptatibus officia provident qui dolorem ab fuga. Obcaecati, molestias placeat neque cum perspiciatis repellendus sequi earum. Velit, totam quae.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus minima minus sint, perspiciatis maiores fugit sit aperiam modi, nihil molestiae natus repellendus odit harum amet veniam. Officia incidunt perferendis vero impedit ullam deleniti facilis dolorum! Incidunt excepturi harum minima eos accusamus, iure aut mollitia commodi, hic culpa blanditiis optio fugiat quia voluptates suscipit placeat recusandae? Perferendis nobis autem ex dolor velit, quo explicabo, reiciendis facere tempora aperiam temporibus laborum dolorum dignissimos in delectus culpa aliquid error vitae suscipit. Accusamus, assumenda dolore voluptatibus officia provident qui dolorem ab fuga. Obcaecati, molestias placeat neque cum perspiciatis repellendus sequi earum. Velit, totam quae.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus minima minus sint, perspiciatis maiores fugit sit aperiam modi, nihil molestiae natus repellendus odit harum amet veniam. Officia incidunt perferendis vero impedit ullam deleniti facilis dolorum! Incidunt excepturi harum minima eos accusamus, iure aut mollitia commodi, hic culpa blanditiis optio fugiat quia voluptates suscipit placeat recusandae? Perferendis nobis autem ex dolor velit, quo explicabo, reiciendis facere tempora aperiam temporibus laborum dolorum dignissimos in delectus culpa aliquid error vitae suscipit. Accusamus, assumenda dolore voluptatibus officia provident qui dolorem ab fuga. Obcaecati, molestias placeat neque cum perspiciatis repellendus sequi earum. Velit, totam quae.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus minima minus sint, perspiciatis maiores fugit sit aperiam modi, nihil molestiae natus repellendus odit harum amet veniam. Officia incidunt perferendis vero impedit ullam deleniti facilis dolorum! Incidunt excepturi harum minima eos accusamus, iure aut mollitia commodi, hic culpa blanditiis optio fugiat quia voluptates suscipit placeat recusandae? Perferendis nobis autem ex dolor velit, quo explicabo, reiciendis facere tempora aperiam temporibus laborum dolorum dignissimos in delectus culpa aliquid error vitae suscipit. Accusamus, assumenda dolore voluptatibus officia provident qui dolorem ab fuga. Obcaecati, molestias placeat neque cum perspiciatis repellendus sequi earum. Velit, totam quae.</p>
        <button id="down">Save</button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var specialElementHandler = {
              "#main-ticket":function(element, renderer) {
                return true;
              }
            };

            $("#down").click(function() {
              var doc = new jsPDF();

              doc.fromHTML($("#main-ticket").html(), 15,15,{
                "width":170,
                "elementHandlers":specialElementHandler
              })
              doc.save("Ticket.pdf")
            })



          });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting a pdf which consist of 2000 and something pages